# How to make a solid shader in blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, color, color-management

I'm trying to get an accurate RGB `255, 0, 0` color.

Render engine: Cycles

Here's my attempt, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

I've tried using different color management settings, but still pixels jump from `255 0 0` to `255 1 1`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I noticed that if you save your render as 16bit PNG instead of 8bit, photoshop will not see 255 1 1 anymore but all 255 0 0. Can you live with 16bit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The slight deviation in color is caused by dithering. If you want to save accurate values for non-color data, then you have to:

- Set *Dither* to zero in *Output Properties > Post Processing* when you intend to save an 8-bit image
  [image: Dithering]
- Use **one** of the following options: Set the *View Transform* to *Raw*, disable *Save As Render* in the file browser or save as OpenEXR to by pass the color management. The latter is the best approach since OpenEXR can store the actual scene linear values.
  [image: Color management]
  [image: Save as Render options]
  [image: File format]